# How to store vector coordinates in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

what's the best way to store vector coordinates in Matlab? 
For example, h is the height of the image, w is the width, how can I do this (pseudocode):

```
vectors = [];
for i=1:h
    for j=1:w
       vectors += p(i,j);
    end
end
```

To get the kth p object from vectors, I can use vector(k).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array growth in MATLAB works by indexing past the last element:

```
vectors(end+1) = p(i,j);
```

Conventional wisdom is that it is better to pre-allocate your array and use indexing, but [automatic array growth has become much more efficient](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/), especially for `cell`s and arrays of non-builtin objects.

However, you can just get what you want out of `p` directly via `[ii,jj] = ind2sub(size(p),k); p(jj,ii)`.  Note the order `jj,ii` to match your loop semantics, which would create a vector that indexes the elements of `p` in a row-major order vs. MATLAB's native column-major ordering.  That is, `p(2)` refers to row 2, column 1 of `p`, but your `vectors(2)` would contain to row 1, column 2 of `p` using your loop order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p(k)` directly. It is equivalent to `p(i,j)` where `[i,j] = ind2sub([h w], k)`.

- [Documentation for `ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)

<sub>Unless I didn't understand your question…</sub>